# Defining relations between functions in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, code-review, logic

I would like to find a way to implement the following in Mathematica:

---

Let $F$ be the set of real functions $f_1,f_2,\ldots f_n$. The function $\min$ is defined as follows...

$$\min F=f_i\iff \forall j.\lim_{x\to\infty}[f_i(x)-f_j(x)]\le0$$

Let $h:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ and $f,g:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. The relation $R_h$ is defined as follows...

$$R_h(f,g)\iff\exists x,y.\forall z>y. h(\min\{f,g\}(z),x)>\max\{f,g\}(z)$$

---

For the first of these, I've opted to define a binary operator `FuncLess` which behaves for functions much the same way as `<=` for numbers:

```
FuncLess[f_,g_]:=Limit[f[x]-g[x],x->Infinity]<=0
```

This seemed more practical to me since the minimum and maximum can be found using a loop, and I don't need to deal with the 'forall'. Still, if there's a more efficient way to do this, I would like to know.

For the second relation, $R_h$, I'm not sure what to do. I tried inputting the expression as-is:

```
FuncR[h_][f_,g_]:=
    If[
        FuncLess[f,g],
        Exists[{x,y},ForAll[z,z>y,h[f[z],x]>g[z]]],
        Exists[{x,y},ForAll[z,z>y,h[g[z],x]>f[z]]]
    ]
```

but this proved ineffective. I'm not sure how Mathematica evaluates quantifiers, but I imagine that I'm not using them correctly.

**Example**

```
In[31]:= f[x_]:=x^2

In[32]:= g[x_]:=x^3

In[33]:= h[x_,y_]:=x^y

In[34]:= FuncLess[f,g]

Out[34]= True
```

Ideally, I want `FuncR[h,f,g]` to return `True`, but it only returns the expression. I've tried using `Reduce[FuncR[h,f,g],{x,y,z},Reals]`, but this returns the message:

`Reduce: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce`

Comment: Can you provide examples for `f`, `g` and `h`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`AsymptoticGreater`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticGreater)/[`AsymptoticLess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticLess):

```
FuncR[h_][f_,g_] := Switch[AsymptoticLess[f[x],g[x],x->Infinity],
    True,
    AsymptoticGreater[h[f[z],x], g[z],z->Infinity],

    False,
    AsymptoticGreater[h[g[z],x], f[z],z->Infinity],

    _,
    Indeterminate
]
```

For your example:

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := x^3
h[x_,y_] := x^y

FuncR[h][f, g]
```

> ConditionalExpression[True, x > 3/2]